# How works int64_t on computers with size of machine word equals to 32 bits?

Tags: c++, int

So it can be realised as two int32_t. Is this true?

Also I hear that it depends from the compilers. Is any other variants for realisation? It seems that int64_t can't be like int32_t(both weigh 4 bytes).

Comment: The question looks kinda obvious. Do you have anything more specific in mind? Maybe clarify what you mean by "`int64_t` can't be like `int32_t`"?

Comment: @anatolyg, edit.

Answer (score 1):

> So int64_t can be realised as two int32_t. Is this true?

Yes, it is true.

A int64_t consists of 8 octets. Two int32_t consist of 8 octets. There is exactly as many bits, and therefore they can represent exactly as many states, therefore you can map one pair of int32_t values into a single int64_t value and back.

Comment: I know about this opportunity. But how it works in situation from the question header?

Comment: Long time ago, in days of the 8-bit micro, 16-bit quantities were represented as two eight-bit quantities.  This brought about the terms Big Endian and Little Endian.  The same handling algorithm can be applied to 64-bit quantities on a 32-bit processor.